# Why do C++ function objects need reference type member variables?

Tags: c++, function-object

This is a newbie C++ question. I was reading the "Function object" article in Wikipedia. The article has an example in C++ similar to the following:

```
struct printClass {
  int &count;

  printClass(int &n) : count(n) {}

  void operator()(int &i) const {
      count++;
      cout << i << "[" << count << "] ";
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    vector<int> a(5, 7);
    a[4] = -1;
    a.resize(10, 3);
    int state = 0;
    for_each(a.rbegin(), a.rend(), printClass(state));
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does it fail to compile when count is a regular variable not a reference type? [Demo](http://ideone.com/aLCw3e)
2. Why does it fail to compile it I change the `ctor` to the following? [Demo](http://ideone.com/bKcQ9q)

   `printClass(int &n) { count  = n; }`

Thanks.

EDIT: Thanks for explaining. I see that the following version works, too. Is there a reason for chosing one over another?

```
struct printClass {
  int count;

  printClass(int n) { count  = n; }

  void operator()(int &i) {
      count++;
      cout << i << "[" << count << "] ";
  }
};
```

EDIT: Based on iammilind's reply, here is the 3rd version that works too using `const_cast<int &>`.

```
struct printClass {
  int count ;

  printClass(int n) : count(n) {}

  void operator()(int &i) const {
      const_cast<int &>(count)++;
      cout << i << "[" << count << "] ";
  }
};
```

Comment: Please show us the exact code you're trying to compile, and the exact error message(s) you're getting.

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact example I am trying. PTAL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (1) Why does it fail to compile when count is a regular variable not a
>   reference type?

This is a very interesting question. The question should be rather, why the code compiles when `count` is declared as a reference. :)

The regular variable fails because `int count` is not modifiable inside a `const` qualified function `operator()(int &i) const;`.

References are little different. In your code you are declaring the method as `const`, which means that `count` which is referring to `i`, now cannot refer to anything else.
But that's anyway not possible due to nature of references :). One cannot change reference binding after the initialization.
`operator()` just checks whether you are changing the binding of `count` to anything else or not? And the answer is always no. Because `count++` changes the value referred by `count` and not the binding.

In your code, it doesn't matter if a member method is `const` or not when it comes to `int& count`.

Relate `int& count;` to `int* const p_count;` and try to simulate the situation on your own.

> (2) Why does it fail to compile it I change the ctor to the following?
>   `CountFrom(int &n) { count = n; }`

Because reference must be assigned to a variable while initialization. In simple example;

```
int i, &r;  // error, because 'r' not initialized
r = i;  // this is not initialization but a copy
```

On a side note, you should be extra careful when you are dealing with reference variables inside a `class`. Because it's easy to mess up with their scope and validity.
For example, here the validity of `count` is dependent on the scope of `i`.

**Edit**: After your 2nd edit, it's very trivial to know  why that version works.
Because `count` is now a simple variable. It can be skipped from initialization in the initializer list of the constructor unlike reference.
Moreover the `const` correctness of the `operator()` is gone, so any member variable of the `class` can now be modified inside it.

You should choose a `const` version of the member method, if you want to state that no `class` member "must" change inside it (unless any variable is `mutable` or you use `const_cast`). In all other cases use the normal version of the member method. They both can co-exist as well depending on your business logic. This is a bit of a broad question and it's worth to have another thread for this.